# Permalinks in Wordpress - Error 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am running wordpress locally using Xampp.
I have been trying to get permalinks to work on my WordPress site but I keep getting a 404 Error when I set permalinks to anything other then Default. When I set the permalinks to default than all the links work. As soon as I change them to for example Post name I get the 404 error.

Things I've tried:

- I have removed the # from `#LoadModule rewrite_module
  modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Set `AllowOverride All` in the section bellow

  ```
  # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
  #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
  #
  AllowOverride All
  ```
- The .htaccess file is being generated. It contains the following content:

  `# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /4.0%20WordPress%20Theme%20Development/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /4.0%20WordPress%20Theme%20Development/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>`
- I tried deleting the .htaccess file and have Wordpress remake it

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Well most likely the `.` in `4.0` is throwing it. Not very good form to have a folder with spaces either.

Comment: I just migrated my wordpress site to a folder called `wordpress` and everything is working correctly. You were correct about the `.` in `4.0` was causing the error. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!